# Create binary variable C conditional on partial match between columns A and B

Tags: r

I'd like to create a binary variable, C, conditional on 1 or more match between entries in variables A and B. So in the case of A, row 1 entry "123" is equal to 3 separate entries, "1,2,3", and if B contains at least one of these numbers then column C would contain a "1" for 1+ match.

All of the entries contains integers 1-10 for each row in A and B. so something else I need to do is make sure the code does not mismatch between 1 and 10.

ie: 104="10,4"; 1345="1,3,4,5", so 1 and 10 are different entries that I don't want confused for match.

```
A: 123, 345, 259, 459, 104

B: 134, 452, 349, 594, 391

C: 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
```

I've tried stringr package's str_detect as well as purr() but these are missing several entries that have matching single integers:

```
A: 123, 345, 259, 459, 104

B: 134, 452, 349, 594, 391

df = df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(C = purrr::map2_dbl(.x=A,.y=B,~ifelse(grepl(.y,.x),1,0)))
```

which gives the result:

```
C: 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

essentially it codes "0" for match values that aren't aligned in the same position...

any suggestions for how to fix this?? i've tried the any() function but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution based in the tidyverse can look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  mutate(Ax = map_chr(str_extract_all(A, str_c(10:1, collapse = '|')),
                      ~ str_c(.x, collapse = '|')),
         C = +str_detect(B, Ax)) %>%
  select(-Ax)

#       A     B     C
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1   123   134     1
# 2   345   452     1
# 3   259   349     1
# 4   459   594     1
# 5   104   391     0
```

Data

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(123, 345, 259, 459, 104), B = c(134, 452, 
349, 594, 391)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Tolerating a long line, we could have put the making of `Ax` into the making of `C` (which would have saved us the lines from `mutate(Ax` and `select(-Ax)`. That would also perform better. But it would read less well.

Starting from the inside and moving out, `str_c(10:1, collapse = '|')` gives us `'10|9|8...|1'`. The descending order ensures that `10` is matched before `1`. `str_extract_all()` uses `'10|9|8...|1'` to display matches from `A` in a list of vectors. `map_chr()` collapses the vectors inside the list and returns a character vector `Ax` with `Ax[1]` as `'1|2|3'`. `Ax` is then used inside `str_detect()` to provide a vector of bools (`C`) indicating the presence of one or more of the elements from the entries of `Ax` in `B`. `+` converts `C` from `TRUE-FALSE` to `1-0`.

Comment: wow thanks, works perfectly! would you mind explaining the logic behind the solution just for future reference?

Comment: @hongpastry: My pleasure. I have added a bit of explanation to my post.